# Different group by parameters according to different conditions in c#

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, group-by

I have a class Person having properties as PersonId, PersonAdress, PersonSalary

I have three different cases when I have to apply group by which is
1. When only PersonAdress is null
2. When only PersonSalary is null
3. When both PersonAdress and PersonSalary are null.

PersonId cannot be null.

All these info is in the list List  personList.

Can someone help me here?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: currently i am dividing the main list into three acc to the three cases and then seperately grouping them as per the three cases and then combining the three lists again with distinct to avoid redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define an anonymous lambda to define the grouping. But you can also use an existing method.

```
List<Person> personList = ...;
var agg = personList.GroupBy(Aggregator);
foreach (var gr in agg) {
    Console.WriteLine("Group {0} has {1} persons", gr.Key, gr.Count());
}

private static int Aggregator(Person p) {
    if (p.PersonAddress == null && p.PersonSalary == null) {
        return 3;
    } else if (p.PersonSalary == null) {
        return 2;
    }
    return 1;
}
```